# How can I change the pool ball detection code to OpenCV to remove the shaking?

Tags: python, opencv

I'm using pool ball detection with the HoughCircles function in OpenCV.

```
import numpy as np
import cv2 as cv
cap = cv.VideoCapture(1)
if not cap.isOpened():
    print("Cannot open camera")
    exit()
while True:
    # Capture frame-by-frame
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    # if frame is read correctly ret is True
    if not ret:
        print("Can't receive frame (stream end?). Exiting ...")
        break
    # Our operations on the frame come here
    grayFrame = cv.cvtColor(frame, cv.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    blurFrame = cv.medianBlur(grayFrame,5)
    circles = cv.HoughCircles(blurFrame, cv.HOUGH_GRADIENT, 1, 10,
                              param1=15, param2=25, minRadius=10, maxRadius=20)
    print(circles)
    flag = np.any(circles)
    if flag:
        circles = np.uint16(np.around(circles))
        for i in circles[0, :]:
            # draw the outer circle
            cv.circle(frame, (i[0], i[1]), i[2], (0, 0, 255), 2)
            # draw the center of the circle
            cv.circle(frame, (i[0], i[1]), 2, (0, 255, 0), 3)
    else:
        continue
        # Display the resulting frame
    cv.imshow('frame', frame)
    if cv.waitKey(1) == ord('q'):
        break
# When everything done, release the capture
cap.release()
cv.destroyAllWindows()
```

And I get this result:
https://youtu.be/Hc7pHGq7bkU

Original video:
https://youtu.be/JrxOq1V9cTQ

What can I add or change to remove the shaking

Comment: throw Hough away. use inRange or simple blob detector

Comment: Can i use this with different color balls? And why can't I use Hough?